# Detecting if text is non-English

Tags: php, python, text, nlp, language-detection

What is the most accurate method for detecting if a text (specifically Instagram comments) are non-English? I am happy to use any high-level language, such as Python, PHP, etc.

```
$ sudo pip2 install guess_language
>>> from guess_language import guessLanguage
>>> guessLanguage('la vita e bella')
'UNKNOWN'
>>> guessLanguage('today is a good day')
'UNKNOWN'
>>> guessLanguage('ボウリング・フォー・コロンバイン(字幕版)')
'ja'
```

and with

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring

      if(strlen($comment->text) == mb_strlen($comment->text, 'utf-8')) {
         echo '- '.$comment->text."\n";
    }
```

I get many things with English character which are not English:
examples:

```
- Khoda be khanevadehashon sabr bede tahamol konan
- Akhey...
- Eshghi
- K
- :-)
- Ey khodaa
- ...
- @samaneaghazamani1990 vaaaaay khoda chejoori payam dadan?
- :(
- Elahiiiii
- May Allah please with them and grant higher rank of jannah salutes to the  bravehearts @taraneh_alidoosti @fanpagemostafazamani
- Elaaaahiii
- Roohetoon shad.
- :'(
- Roheshon shad!! Yadeshon gerami!!
- .:'(
- :-(
- Oooo
- Awli
```

I don't want to use something like Google Translate as I am dealing with lots of data.

Update:

```
$ sudo pip2 install langdetect
>>> from langdetect import detect
>>> detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
'en'
>>> detect("today is a good day.")
'so'
>>> detect("la vita e bella!")
'it'
>>> detect("khoobi? khoshi?")
'so'
>>> detect("wow")
'pl'
>>> detect("what a day")
'en'
>>> detect("yay!")
'so'
```

Does 'so' refer to unknown? I was expecting that `today is a good day` be considered as `en`!

Comment: Trigrams is usually enough, even of fairly short text.

Comment: See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect/1.0.1

Comment: @JuanT please see the update!

Comment: According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 it's an error, it's Somali

Comment: A simple solution would be, keep the most used 1000 words in English in a hashmap. search the text and check whether it has those words. Top 3000 words means %90 of English written language.

Comment: you can try using polyglot library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polyglot

Comment: @MonaJalal Questions asking for recommendations for tools and libraries are offtopic, it's in the docs and right in the 'flag' menu. Likely why you are getting the response.

Comment: Please delete this question! I asked from the community but I don't know why it doesn't get deleted. Thanks!

Comment: It already has an answer with +3 votes . I don't think it would do any good to anybody if your question gets deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ployglot](http://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html) package's language detection feature.

```
>>> from polyglot.detect import Detector
>>> print(Detector('today is a good day.').language)
name: English     code: en       confidence:  95.0 read bytes:  1792
```

Comment: *Thank you, how can we tell if langid is better or polyglot.detect in general?

Comment: I don't think any of them detects language perfectly for all. To decide which one is better, one needs to perform some tests on both. Polyglot has some additional features like detecting through mixed text etc. I am not sure it can be done by langid.

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you use an spellchecker. It will return spelling is not right if the word doesn't belong to a language. Use that to determine if a word is English or not. 
Here is an open source spell checker: http://aspell.net/

Every OS has spell check built in. You can use those as well.

Comment: The spelling of words (for example, English words like souvenir) does not have to do with exactly which language it belongs in. (Souvenir is also a French verb, which cannot exactly be "spellchecked", per se.)

Comment: There are also words that are common between English and other languages so you can't use a spell checker here to check the validity of a word belonging to just the English language.  For example, *rendezvous* is found in both [English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rendezvous) and [French](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/rendez-vous) dictionaries, though admittedly it is a French word.